# Space at the bottom of the screen (iOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, xib

There is a space appearing, only if I put that the status bar is hidden, at the bottom of the screen like that:

[image]

But it doesn't appear in xcode:

[image]

P.S: It's the second view, which I open with:

```
UIViewController* flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:flipViewController.view];
```

Comment: Looks like you have taken into account the status bar.

Comment: @Popeye What do you mean?

Comment: In the interface builder you can include the status bar. By selecting the .xib file you want to work on >> select the view >> in the right hand side select the 4th tab so it has the title "Simulated Metrics" >> on there, there should be the option for status bar.

Comment: @Popeye But I don't want a status bar... And anyway, if I put it visible in xib, the space is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the status bar with iOS 7.

Add the following code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


}
```

Comment: Technically this is wrong, but only because the call to super should go first.

Comment: It says: "Property edgesForExtendedLayout not found on object of type GameController". Btw, I have xcode 4 and iOS 5

Comment: @Mageek That makes sense then as `edgesForExtendedLayout` is in the iOS 7 API could you add this detail to your question so no one else gives an answer for iOS7.